# How to keep HTML lines under 80 characters?

Tags: html

I've been told to keep HTML lines under 80 characters. I'm using Atom, and there is displayed a line to remind it.

I've found a lot of discussions about it but no example at all. For example, I have this line:

```
<p>
Born and raised in Valencia (Spain), graduated and married in Seville (Spain) and now I'm working and growing my own very family in Vienna (Austria).
</p>
```

and if I split it I get this:

```
<p>
Born and raised in Valencia (Spain), graduated and married in Seville (Spa
in) and now I'm working and growing my own very family in Vienna (Austria)
.
</p>
```

But when I look it on the browser there's a space between some words:

> Born and raised in Valencia (Spain), graduated and married in Seville
>   **(Spa_in)** and now I'm working and growing my own very family in Vienna **(Austria)_.**

*(I typed underscores to point the generated spaces)*

How can I avoid this? And when it comes to code: How to split tags, attributes, links, etc.? For example:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
```

or this

```
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Ask a Question" />
```

Does anyone know any resource to consult?

By the way, for the moment I'm just coding in HTML and not using JS at all, and I need to keep it like this if it's possible.

Comment: Why don't you just put the carriage return in the whitespace instead of in the middle of a word?  Does every line have to be *exactly* 80 characters?  Why is there a width limit in the first place?  Is this being coded on a terminal from the 80s?

Comment: https://discuss.atom.io/t/automatically-hard-wrap-lines/8986/4

Comment: Is this for compatibility with punchcards?

Comment: Hi, it's just about "HTML Coding Conventions". Readability and such stuff. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split it *close* to 80 symbols.

```
<p>
    Born and raised in Valencia (Spain),
    graduated and married in Seville
    (Spain) and now I'm working and
    growing my own very family
    in Vienna (Austria).
</p>
```

For tag splitting - split on every attribute:

```
<link
    rel="apple-touch-icon image_src"
    href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"
>
```

---

Please note that it's sometimes better to exceed line limit to increase readability.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was thinking too much strictly.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it this way; you said **under 80** so you don't need always 80.

```
<p>
Born and raised in Valencia (Spain), graduated and married in Seville
(Spain) and now I'm working and growing my own very family in Vienna
(Austria).
</p>
```

Other example with multiline property (you have to use tabs not spaced for the URL to work), but I recommend not to use this (like Justinas already mentioned in the comments), because it can lead to problems, sometimes it's better to adopt the rules:

```html
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/
 img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful.

Comment: You have ruined `src` url. Now it contains spaces. It's side effect and not always works good

Comment: Thanks for the info, I also updated my answer with an recommendation not to use this. But if he is not allowed to exceed the lines for whatever reason, I don't know any other workaround for `src` url.